# Diseño de una corvatura con CSS

Tags: html, css

Debo hacer este diseño con CSS, pero tengo unas dudas con respecto a esta corvatura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fondo es naranja pero esta sobrepuesto otra caja con este redondeado, he pensado hacerlo con z-index pero no me ha funcionado, agradecería si alguien pudiera darme una idea de como podría hacerlo

Esta es la vista completa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes hacerlo de esta manera en CSS:

```css
.fondo{
    background: orange;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.curvatura{
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0; /* Esto modificará los bordes de arriba, pero no los de abajo */
    padding: 15px;
    color: #161616;
    background: #FFF
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo">
    <div class="curvatura">
        Mi texto
    </div>
</div>
```

Si tienes dudas espero tus comentarios, espero te sirva :D

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, fue útil!

Answer (score 0):

podes posicionarlo relativamente al elemento de abajo , y subirlo ( usamos `bottom` para que lo empuje desde abajo ) la misma medida que le diste a los `border-radius` `left` y `right`

```css
header { 
height:200px;
background-color:orange ;
text-align:center
}

main{
height:100vh;
background-color:aqua;
border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0 ;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
bottom:50px
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>Contenido principal</main>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo!